# Apache Spark Dataframe - Issue with setting up a not-equal join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that I'm doing a multi-column join.  The first pair of columns is doing an equal comparison and the second pair is a not-equals comparison.  The code looks like this:

```
val arule_1w = itemLHS
      .join(itemRHS, itemLHS("CUST_ID") === itemRHS("CUST_ID") && itemLHS("LHS") != itemRHS("RHS")
```

The resulting data still has rows that contains itemLHS("LHS") = itemRHS("RHS"), which it shouldn't, with the not-equal join.  It maybe user error as well but all my research tells me that format is correct.  All datatypes are string values.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Correct method is `=!=` not `!=`.

Comment: I've tried that and it throws the following error: cannot resolve '((CUST_ID = CUST_ID) && LHS)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((CUST_ID = CUST_ID) && LHS)' (boolean and string).  It's like it doesn't understand what !== is.

Comment: Oh it is a precedence issue. Try `=!=`.

Comment: why in the world is it than  OK with != but ignores it!!

Answer (score -1):

Used below syntaxt
itemLHS("LHS") !== itemRHS("RHS")